# Azure App Service deployment via Container Registry - Issue, Image not running properly

Tags: php, azure, docker, nginx, azure-container-registry

I have the following Dockerfile setup below (PHP / Nginx / Laravel) and this works locally just fine. After building I'm able to run the image by:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 mycontainer.azurecr.io/casapi:latest
```

Locally I'm able to access it by going to localhost:80

Now, after uploading the image to my container registry successfully.
[image]

I then created an App Service that uses that container for deployment or source.

[image]

And lastly I added a Websites_Port config in the configuration per documentation so that I  can expose it and bind hopefully on the app service and container

[image]

Unfortunately I'm still seeing this after saving config changes and restarting the app service:

[image]

The image below is what I see in the App Service logs (if it helps)
[image]

DOCKERFILE:

```
# Base image
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Copy environment file
COPY azure/.env.dev .env

# Copy htaccess file
COPY azure/.htaccess.dev .htaccess

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
        unzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    /var/www/html/storage \
    /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Install Nginx
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        nginx && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log


# Copy custom Nginx configuration
COPY docker-default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default


# Start Nginx and PHP-FPM
CMD service nginx start && php-fpm

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: There's no need to set WEBSITES_PORT since your container listens on port 80. That being said, the issue is not with port binding but with your container failing to start. Enable the application logs and see if you get more info that would help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the image via:
`docker image inspect`

I found out that my image is on architecture: ARM64 (from my Mac m1)
Whereas Azure App Service is on architecture: Linux x86_64

Solution: I had to force build my image for that architecture instead:

```bash
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/casapi:latest -f Dockerfile .
```

And after pushing, it worked!